# How to change cell formatting in Python code?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, beautifulsoup, spreadsheet

I have just written a script that extracts data from an esports website. The script ran perfectly and the excel spreadsheet was made but the issue is it formats each cell to be "General".

The reason this is an issue is because I have past match results that say "08-16" and as the excel sheet is in general, this immediately changes to Aug-16.

Is there anyway I can edit the excel cell format to be "Text" and not "General"?

This is the first time I have learnt web scraping.

```
r = requests.get('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/matches/4991/fnatic')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('tr')
records = []
for result in results:
    date = result.contents[1].text
    event = result.contents[3].text
    opponent = result.contents[7].text
    Map = result.contents[9].text
    Score = result.contents[11].text
    WinorLoss = result.contents[13].text
    records.append((date,event,opponent,Map,Score))
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['date','event','opponent','Map','Score'])
df.to_csv('Fnatic_Match_Stats.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

So in the end I would like the match results that are for example 08-16 to appear as 08-16 and not Aug-16

Comment: you can use data parsing?

Comment: Are you avoiding using quotes or the the leading apostrophe? Have you considered `to_excel`? Also, please note you are creating a CSV file not an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: can you try `df = df.astype('str')`

or if you only want the date to be formatted `df = df.astype('date': 'str')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply concatenate a ' in front to preserve in Excel. For example,

```
Score = "'" + result.contents[11].text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlswriter package to format the cells in excel using python

```
format4 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'd-m-yyyy'})
worksheet.write('A4', number, format4)
```

you can also [refer this link](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html)